# Importing shapefiles to PostGIS on QGIS1.8

Tags: qgis, postgis-2.0

I am trying to import a shapefile into PostGIS from within QGIS 1.8.

The QGIS is based on a server that is not managed by myself. I have requested an upgrade to QGIS 2.0... but this may take some time so in the meantime I am working with 1.8.

I am using SPIT to import shapefiles to PostGIS in QGIS.

The error message I am returned is:

```
Problems inserting features from file: filepath/charcoal.shp
<p>Error while executing the SQL:</p><p>SELECT
f_table_name FROM geometry_columns WHERE
f_table_name='charcoal' AND
f_table_schema='GIS'</p><p> The database said: ERROR: permission denied for relationship geometry_columns </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why SPIT is not working for you and it may be a version thing (either with QGIS or PostGIS).  It could also be that you don't have the correct access permissions on your account on PostGIS and you need to take that up with your database administrator (I'm assuming the PostGIS instance is remote too).  However, what you could do as a work around is use [shp2pgsql](http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg) in PostGIS itself (if you know you have permissions or access to a local PostGIS instance).  This bypasses QGIS altogether.

Comment: At least the message sounds very clear "permission denied for relationship geometry_columns". Check if your account has insert rights on geometry_columns.